# How do I transfer ownership of strings?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and have run into a problem similar to the following a few times:

```
fn main() {
    let mut as_str: Vec<&String> = Vec::new();
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter() {
        let i_str = i.to_string();
        as_str.push(&i_str);
    }
}
```

Which yields the following error:

```
<anon>:6:22: 6:27 error: `i_str` does not live long enough
<anon>:6         as_str.push(&i_str);
                          ^~~~~
```

How do I transfer ownership of the string to the vector (do not want to copy)?  Do I need a lifetime?  Should it be a str or a String (supposing I do not want to mutate the items themselves in the vector)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give the vector a `String`, not a reference to one. A `Foo` is owned, a `&Foo` is borrowed.

```
fn main() {
    let mut as_str: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter() {
        let i_str = i.to_string();
        as_str.push(i_str);
    }
}
```

In your example, you are allocating a `String` inside the for loop body, then taking a reference to it. Since nothing owns the `String`, it is dropped at the end of the loop body. That means that any references would become invalid. Rust prevents this memory safety violation.

In the real world, you'd never need to specify the type here, type inference is enough:

```
fn main() {
    let mut as_str = Vec::new();
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter() {
        let i_str = i.to_string();
        as_str.push(i_str);
    }
}
```

And you'd probably use `map` to convert one slice of things to another:

```
fn main() {
    let as_str: Vec<_> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().map(|i| i.to_string()).collect();
}
```

Incidentally, it never makes sense to have a `&String`; you might as well have a `&str`.

Comment: Just to make sure, the String is moved and not copied in that case correct?  Does one have to explicitly copy in Rust (unlike C++)?

Comment: `let as_str: Vec<_> = (1..6).map(|i| i.to_string()).collect()` is another way to achieve what OP is after.